# Access to a network disk PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, mamp

I was looking for an easy way to read and treat a *.xls file, and I found PHPExcel. All worked perfectly until I tried to access to a file which was in another Network Disk. 
I now use this to access to my *.xls file :

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('//NetworkDisk2/Stuff/.../SomeFile.xls');
```

But, as I said, this ain't working. And I don't know why. When the file and the *.php pages were in the same disk, no problems, all worked just fine.

Could anyone please help me (may be I'm wrong with my path or I don't know) or at least redirect me to another way to do the treatment?

Can it be because of the firewall?

Thanks.

Comment: you can browse only your document root for the website and not the entire filesystem (local or network)

Comment: you have to make sure that filepath is readable from the server runs your php script, like using `is_readable`, check error message etc.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @VolodiaChampenois really? LelioFaieta's post is no-sense here.

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson I still have an "http error 500" when I refresh my *.php page, with the link to another network disk. Even if I'm using `if(is_readable('path'){echo "It's alive!"; }else{ echo "RIP"; }`

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson are you sure? The only option for op is to mount the network drive to a folder in the website directory (checking that the mount is with the right user and permissions for the webser to use it)

Comment: @LelioFaieta Do you think I should try to put a shortcut (to the other network disk) into the folder that contain my *.php file?

Comment: what is your OS? you should mount the drive into the folder (if you are on a *nix OS) or do something similar on windows

Comment: I'm on Windows.

Comment: How can I mount the drive into the folder?

Comment: 'http error 500' means there is error happened when execute your script, check your error log or display it! and again, LelioFaieta's post is no-sense ...

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson Yes thanks, I misstake 7 with Z.... So now, I have the "please wait..." on screen, but that's all, the treatment won't start. And when I try the `if(is_readable('path)'{...}` nothing happen, not even the "please wait...". Just a white screen.

Comment: @VolodiaChampenois  
you have to make sure that filepath is readable from the server, if you don't know how it would be better to ask the sysadmin of your network.

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson I found another way, it works just find for now. I'll look for a less "brutal" way later. For now it'll be ok. (just a c/p script)

Comment: @VolodiaChampenois glad to hear that, you could post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson for now I put a lil something in the excel macro they use every morning which copy past the file to the network disk which hosted the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why, don't know how, but I can't have access with my website to another network disk. I couldn't execute a script all morning same time because the hours of treatments change with the day (never the same twice) so I modify a macro which was use to treat the Excel file and have the good information, so when my coworkers'll execute the macro, a copy of the file created will be paste to the network disk I have access too.

So the answer is to my question is no, we can't have access to a network disk with PHPExcel.

Topic closed guys, you can go home, thanks for all of you.